# Does cloning my HDD to an external HDD leaves the external drive useless?

Tags: external-hdd, cloning

I'm planning to clone my 320gb HDD, having abut 100gb data to a 1tb external HDD. I fear doing so will leave my external hard disk useless. Will it still be possible to store other data there after cloning?

Comment: Is your purpose to backup the data from the 320gb HDD or having a replacement backup you can directly swap if the internal disk breaks down?

Answer (score 0):

Cloning it to the external HD will result in the fact that your external HD will be seen as a 320GB HD.

Not really useful.

Why do you want to clone it and not just copy all the files?